# Add 0 before lines starting with 2

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've got a long list of data. A subset of the data looks like this:

```
debixxx
solxxxx
kkxxx
ericaxxx
2123xxxx
2110xxxx
anthxxxx
2103xxxx
```

I would like for every line that starts with a "2" to have a "0" prefixed so the result would be:

```
debixxx
solxxxx
kkxxx
ericaxxx
02123xxxx
02110xxxx
anthxxxx
02103xxxx
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to Search -> Replace
2. Set search mode - Regular expression
3. Enter to Find what - (^2)
4. Enter to Replace with - 0$1
5. Click Replace All

Cheers)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but your solution changes 2103xxxx to 0103xxxx i.e. it drops the 2. I want to change it to 02103xxxx

Comment: Replacing with 02 works so that's good enough for me. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Please then try to set Replace with - 0$1 and Find What to (^2)